# WaveDataflow reference type when trying to remove a field

Tags: custom-field, crm-analytics

I have a picklist field on Lead that, what I click "Where is this used?", there's a reference to WaveDataflow, which I think is a CRM analytics thing. I'm hoping to remove this field, but can't while this dependency is there.

I can't find out where this is coming from (nobody in the org knows), and I can't pull it down using SFDX (I figured I'd try to see where it's coming from).

Using the following in package.xml and doing a retrieve:

```
<members>*</members>
<name>WaveDataFlow</name>
```

I just get the following error:

```
Entity type 'WaveDataflow' is not available in this organization
```

This is a production org.

How can I track down this dependency to remove it?

Comment: Do you have tableau license enabled for your user?

Comment: I do not. I asked another user that had been using Tableau -- it was recently shut down.

Comment: Do another user who has tableau license able to retrieve or do they see same error?

Comment: Nobody would have a Tableau license anymore

Comment: You would need to have Tableau license if you want to retrieve or view related components

Comment: did you ever find out solution to this?